# Correct way to display a QImage with QGLWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl

How do I display a QImage in a QGLWidget? Do I have to draw a rectangle and add a texture on it or there is a better fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [overpainting](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/overpainting.html) to draw a `QImage` over the `QGLWidget`, but it would certainly be faster pushing the image data out to the GPU by using the image as a texture.